# Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object

Tags: php, oop, authentication, count, fatal-error

I am learning PHP OOP by utilizing a PHP Academy tutorial. The tutorial is a Registration/Login system. I am having trouble on the "Remember Me" portion of the tutorial. This part of the tutorial retains a users selection to be able to stay logged in.
I am having an error:

"Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rikarsen.hol.es\core\init.php on line 32

I have placed the PHP classes below to show what I have done thus far. Since I am new to PHP coding I am unable to locate the problem. Can anyone please help me? If any additional code is needed please let me know so I can supply it to you in order to help you discover my problem.

***init.php***

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS ['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'db' => 'rikars'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user',
        'token_name' => 'token'
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';


if(Cookie::exists(Config::get('remember/cookie_name')) && Session::exists(Config::get('session/session_name'))) {
    $hash = Cookie::get(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
    $hashCheck = DB::getInstance()->get('users_sessions', array('hash', '=', $hash));

    if($hashCheck->count()) {
        echo 'asass';
    }
}
```

I think I made a mistake in ***DB.php***

```
<?php
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_result,
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)){
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            if($this->_query->execute()){
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

            $field      = $where[0];
            $operator   = $where[1];
            $value      = $where[2];

            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function get($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
    }

    public function delete($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('DELETE *', $table, $where);
    }

    public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
        $keys = array_keys($fields);
        $values = null;
        $x = 1;

        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $values .= '?';
            if($x < count($fields)) {
                $values .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function update($table, $id, $fields) {
        $set = '';
        $x= 1;

        foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
            $set .= "{$name} = ?";
            if($x < count($fields)) {
                $set .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

        if($this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;
    }

    public function first() {
        return $this->results()[0];
    }

    public function error() {
        return $this->_error;
    }

    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }
    public function ins() {
        $instance = DB::getInstance();
        $instance->get('users',array('user_id','=','1'));
        if (!$instance->Count()) {
            echo 'No user';
        } else {
            echo 'User exists';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: try $hashCheck = new DB();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method action return false but you expect object.

```
if(Cookie::exists(Config::get('remember/cookie_name')) && Session::exists(Config::get('session/session_name'))) {
    $hash = Cookie::get(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
    $hashCheck = DB::getInstance()->get('users_sessions', array('hash', '=', $hash));

    if($hashCheck === false) {
        echo 'Action return false';
    } else {
        $count = $hashCheck->count();
        if($count) {
            echo 'Its object and count ='.$count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A typical case where using exceptions instead of a boolean return value makes totally sense.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your table name and column names are correct in get method. I was having the same problem and this was the solution that worked for me.